# How to include multitenant tenant id in join tables in spring boot 3 project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I'm working on a Spring Boot 3 project,  using the new `@TenantId` annotation for multitenant separation within my Hibernate entities.

This is all good, and I can see all my tables include the expected tenant column until I noticed that any join tables, such as those generated by `@ManyToMany` relationships, do not possess the tenant column.

Does anyone know how to also have Hibernate automatically manage tenancy through join tables in addition to regular entities?

Comment: This data is tied to the entities themselves, so most providers do not duplicate the data into the non-entity tables (relations, embeddable etc). If you need to manage it, I would suspect your best option is to make entities of them all.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply.   I suspected I might have to use my own join entity,  it's a bit disappointing that the tenancy features don't cater for associations out of the box.

Comment: Are there any examples on how to do this? A quick google doesn't show much.